# Custom memory allocators or memory pools

Tags: c#, memory, heap-memory, allocation

I am using a third-party networking library and in order to send a network message I need to create a new instance of the `NetworkMessage` class. This is inefficient because the application needs to run very fast and there are a lot of messages sent around, so I am looking for a way to avoid dynamic memory allocation for every message.

If the `NetworkMessage` was a struct then we wouldn't have a problem. Also I cannot store a number of precreated `NetworkMessage` instances because the message arguments can only be passed in the constructor and they cannot be altered later on. I cannot change anything in the `NetworkMessage` class as it is third party.

Is there a way to create a memory pool in C# and then use something similar to the placement new operator from C++ to create objects from that pool? ( I know that there is no placement new operator in C# ). I'm looking for a way to initialize a block of memory and then use chunks of that memory to create instances of the `NetworkMessage` class from that.

Comment: Have you actually *measured* that this allocation problem is causing a slowdown? The .net allocator and GC is pretty heavily optimised for the "Loads of tiny short lived objects" case. If you're just guessing, you're likely to be wrong.

Comment: As others said, are you absolutely sure this is your bottleneck? How exactly does `NetworkMessage` look like? Is it `sealed`?

Comment: Dude, that's what the dotNet garbage collected heap ***is***. You are already doing it.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. You are right I am not sure that this will be a bottleneck yet as we are still in early development. It is just a thought for the future in case it becomes a bottleneck and coming from a C++ background I was not aware that memory allocation was that optmized for tiny short lived objects in C#. So I guess it will not prove to be a problem. I was worried because there are going to be thousands of messages created per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we go on, one remark: memory allocation is super-efficient in .NET. It is not an expensive operation like it was in COM.

That being said, I see two solutions:

One thing you can do is to simply **create a pool of NetworkMessage instances yourself.** You can then take them and release them from the pool using a simple manager class.

Another option is to **use an inversion of control container** such as [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/), [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx) or [NInject](http://ninject.org/). Such containers handle dependency creation and object lifetime management for you.

Good luck!

Comment: I think pool won't work here, because the arguments are known only when the message is needed and they have to be passed into a constructor. And I don't see how would IoC make any difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I said above I was not aware that C# is that optimized for small dynamic allocations!

Comment: It wuuld be nice if downvoters motivate their downvote!

Comment: It's still too slow for performance-critical applications that allocate numerous small objects.

Answer (score 1):

What does NetworkMessage take as an input parameters in the constructor?

Does it take a byte array? If this is the case, this would be a better candidate for pooling rather than the NetworkMessage class itself.

Microsoft has a [Networking Sample](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nclsamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=socket%20performance) that illustrates how pooling of a large byte array could work in a Sample Async Socket server

Comment: That's a good point - the arguments of this class are key-value pair objects which could be pre-created in an object pool so if memory allocation actually BECOMES a problem I will definietely think about doing that!